# When can I clean up archived WAL files?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.2

I need some help understanding the how archived WAL files are used and when I can clean them up.

Currently we have a master database replicating to a slave, but every so often our master database server runs out of disk space because the files archived using `archive_command` build up and we have to manually remove them.  I feel like we're missing something if we have to manually remove old archived WAL files because there are too many that the file system runs out of disk space...

Having said that, I'm not sure I understand the replication process enough to start deleting files and be confident that I'm not screwing anything up.  Does our slave use the archived files created by `archive_command` or does it rely only on the files in `$PG_DATA/pg_xlog` directory to maintain a consistent state with the master?

<s>If that's the case, and we're doing a `pg_dump` of our master every six hours, could I update our backup script to also clear out all archive files that exist at the start of the `pg_dump` (once the `pg_dump` is complete of course)?</s> from the docs:

> Note: pg_dump and pg_dumpall do not produce file-system-level backups
>   and cannot be used as part of a continuous-archiving solution. Such
>   dumps are logical and do not contain enough information to be used by
>   WAL replay.

I just want to make sure that however we clean up the archived files, we still have what we need for replication to continue as well as be able to perform a PITR in since the last base backup.

Our archive command is `cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/9.2/archive/%f` and here is our `recovery.conf` file from the slave:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=<ip-address> port=<port> user=rep password=<password> sslmode=require'
trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger.5432'
```

Comment: Can you please add your `archive_command` and the contents of your `recovery.conf` on your slave to the question. That will help greatly in answering your question.

Comment: It would seem that I've mixed to different topics together here... The replication relies on the WAL files in `pg_xlog/` but the archived WAL files are related to backup and restoration.  Also, since we're currently using `pg_dump` for our database backups, the point about keeping archived WAL files is moot because they can't be played on top of a restored `pg_dump` file.

Comment: If anybody is interested I blogged about our mistake! https://medium.com/@jordanthomasg/postgres-wal-files-replication-or-backup-7810045968a2#.mbmf3k6um

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WAL Files are a record of all the transactions that have taken place .. but that's it - a delta between state before and state after, essentially.  Which means you have to have a BASE to start off of before you can apply any WAL Files.

If you clear out WAL archives without creating a new BASE, then you will be in trouble when you try to restore your database (via PITR) from them.

If you are going to delete WAL files, then you need to make sure you have a valid base to build from again afterward.

Read the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/continuous-archiving.html) on WAL archiving for more information.

In terms of streaming replication, I believe that only uses files located in pg_xlog...  (files are not archived before they are sent, IIRC)

> If that's the case, and we're doing a pg_dump of our master every six hours, could I update our backup script to also clear out all archive files that exist at the start of the pg_dump (once the pg_dump is complete of course)?

Not entirely ... pg_dump creates a file that contains the information of your whole database that can be given to pg_restore...  For PITR, you actually need to create a file-level "backup" by copying your database files and WAL files (after issuing a pg_start_backup)

Comment: Currently going back through the documentation... Looks like `pg_dump` does not create an adequate backup for the purposes of continuous archiving and point-in-time recovery.

Comment: The more I'm looking through this issue, I believe you are correct that replication only relies on the files in `pg_xlog/`.

Comment: Perhaps update the end of your answer to account for the documentation that clearly states `pg_dump` does not produce a backup compatible with WAL archives.

Comment: Ah yes - sorry.  I got pg_dump mixed up with the backup process.